# Best way to phrase a 'side project'

Tags: resume, title

I have previously worked as a company director for a now liquidated business.

In addition to the above company's main objective - property development, I had a side 'money earner' of advertising signs (related to the business).

How should I best phrase this on my cv? Subsidiary interest? Side project?

Comment: Is this a responsibility you had while employed? Then it goes under "other responsibilities" of your position. If you say "side project" or "interest" I tend to think of projects that are not associated with your employment. For example a pet project that you work on on off hours is a side project.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to list it alongside your existing experience while working at company X or you could choose to list it as it's own job. Though be careful about doing the latter if there wasn't much to it or the experience isn't that substantial on it's own.

Alternatively you could instead list it as a project rather than experience or choose to informally add it to other parts of your CV.